# TailwindCSS/daisyUI Dropdown Component Fails To Change Color

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, daisyui

I'm working with TailwindCSS and daisyUI to build a dropdown menu. The code is below.

The problem is that when a dropdown menu item is clicked on (when it becomes active), it becomes purple, even though I'm using the utility class `bg-white` on the `<li>` element. How can I customize the color of the dropdown menu items on click? I'd really prefer a solution that is CSS-only, as I am using the CDN versions of Tailwind and daisyUI (and therefore have no `tailwind.config.js` to modify.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@2.15.3/dist/full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="dropdown dropdown-hover">
  <a class="mx-2 text-2xl">ABOUT</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-content menu bg-blue-primary items-center">
    <li class="bg-white"><a>Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="bg-white"><a>Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had changed the color to `pink-200`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@2.15.3/dist/full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="dropdown dropdown-hover">
  <a class="mx-2 text-2xl">ABOUT</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-content menu bg-blue-primary items-center">
    <li class="bg-white"><a class=" hover:bg-pink-200 focus:bg-pink-200">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="bg-white"><a class="hover:bg-pink-200 focus:bg-pink-200">Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad, I am able to help you

Answer (score 2):

I tried adding `active:bg-white` to the `<a>` tags that were changing bg color, but DaisyUI overrides it.

Without being able to change the config, what I have done is added the style override in a `<style>` block.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@2.15.3/dist/full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
.menu :where(li:not(.menu-title):not(:empty))>:where(:not(ul):active) {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: black;
}
</style>
<div class="dropdown dropdown-hover">
  <a class="mx-2 text-2xl">ABOUT</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-content menu bg-blue-primary items-center">
    <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```